# Firebase Database V9 Return last item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat system where a chat contains multiple messages the structure looks like this below:

```
 - messages
   - ChatId123
      - MesageId123
      - MessageId456
```

I just want to retrieve the last message sent in this case `MessageId456` I assume I need to use `orderByKey()`. The keys are generated using `push()` how can I correctly query and filter for the last item?

```
const query = query(ref(db, `messages/ChatId123`), orderByKey())
return query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `limitToLast` to get just the last item(s) from a query:

```
query(ref(db, `messages/ChatId123`), orderByKey(), limitToLast(1))
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be to add timestamp field in the message object like "SendAt" and orderBy this value :

```js
const q = query(ref(db, `messages/ChatId123`), orderBy("SendAt", "desc"), limit(1));
```

[image: example Firestore side]

Comment: Your answer is for the Firestore database, but in the question they're using the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API of one cannot be used on the other.